# How to deal with "${applicationid}" in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I'm trying to create bindings for Zendesk library and I faced with a problem.

Zendesk Belvedere library (belvedere-1.0.2.1.aar) contains a file provider in its manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    ...

    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="com.zendesk.belvedere.BelvedereFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.belvedere.attachments"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/belvedere_attachment_storage" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When Gradle is used as build tool, it puts this aar to the APK file and it replaces `${applicationId}.belvedere.attachments` with `com.your_package_name_here.belvedere.attachments` in the merged manifest file. It's fine.

However, Xamarin handles it differently. Here is what I found in the manifest of my final APK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    ...
    ...

    <application 
        ...
        ...
        <provider 
            android:name="com.zendesk.belvedere.BelvedereFileProvider" 
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket" 
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                android:resource="@xml/belvedere_attachment_storage" />
        </provider>
        ...
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Obviously, `dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket` is not what I need.

Seems everything works, however it makes impossible to install several Xamarin applications that use these bindings, because all of them would have conflicting providers with the same authority (and user would get `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error).

Is there a way to change `dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket` in the manifest?

**Edit:** A small sample that shows the problem: https://gitlab.com/lassana/ZendeskXamarin/

Comment: Post code of your custom content provider that you used in Xamarin.Android

Comment: @Pravin this provider is not mine, it is from aar library. Actually, I do not use it in my code.

Comment: Is there a way to get a sample project of this in action? My best guess would be that this project might need either custom MSBuild functionality or we need to fix the parser.

Comment: @JonDouglas I've added a link to the repository.

Comment: `${name}`s were supposed to be pre-processed by gradle but its not part of xamarin binding building process. I've looked through xamarin build tools sources just for fun but could not find any way to hook into this process, all the Transformations are not applicable to manifest file if I understood correctly. I can only suggest poor workaround - unzip aar, patch manifest. zip it again , rename to ..aar and you will be just fine

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Remove the file provider from the Manifest file in the `.aar` and add it manually to your app's manifest...

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks, that's what I finally did. Can you write an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft team, Xamarin.Build.Download (0.4.12-preview) finally [fixes this bug](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/444#issuecomment-419226892).

So, you should follow these steps:

1. Update the Nuget Package to 0.4.12-preview3
2. Restart the IDE
3. Delete all cached locations of NuGet Packages
4. Delete bin/obj
5. Rebuild

Answer (score 6):

The current `Xamarin.Android` manifest merge build task, up to and including 
version `7.1.0.19`, does not provide any bundeID/ApplicationID (`${}`} substitution in the merged manifest like `gradle` does.

This is just a *limitation* in the manifest processing/merge task, thus you are ending up with `dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket` in your final manifest and will have to correct **both** manifests yourself.

The only current solution know to me to avoid the manifest merge task and it's limitation is to:

1. **Remove** the file provider entry from the '.aar`'s manifest
2. **Add** the complete file provider entry your app's manifest

Note: You *have* to do both steps

Depending upon how often the `.aar` is changing and where you are sourcing the `.aar` file from:

- Manually unzip the `aar`, remove the entry and re-zip the `aar` (the quickest way)
- Automated this in a build step via a shell script using bash or powershell cmds
- Write a MSBuild C#-based Task to do it.
- Request that the `aar` manifest be changed upstream (not likely to happen ;-) since it works fine w/ `gradle`)

FYI: Personally I have seen the `${applicationId}` issue you are having a few times. I have written build scripts (`bash/.ps1`) to do the manifest fix-up as it seems to always be some special case in the `.arr`'s manifest that I am dealing with.

Comment: Thanks again. What is really interesting is that Xamarin [tries to handle](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/24f2aec113857b5c583e14959b9af08ad45b22b1/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Utilities/ManifestDocument.cs#L784) "applicationId" build variable.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin I've seen that also... I believe the last time I traced it that `ManifestDocument.Save` method is applied *after* the manifest merge from the `.aar` and thus it is already been expanded (in a broken way) and no substitution occurs. There was a bug filed for this type of manifest support a long time ago, but it was done through Xamarin Support (before MSFT purchase) from an prior Enterprise customer (and client of mine). I had a bug # at one time but it was private and not being the original filing customer do not know the resolution of it...

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin A public bug should really be filed with your SO question linked to it... I'm *assuming* not many people have run into this issue since it has not been noticed/fixed in the last 2/3 years... I'm glad you got it to work ;-) I've worked w/ a lot of `Xamarin.Android` and Java devs. In MVVM terms, we build pure Java UIs for the *V*iews, bind them and use C# for the *V*iew*M*odels and *M*odels. A very performant and memory efficient design and outsourcing the Android UI in Java is easy due to huge Android/Java Dev. base so dealing w/ `.aar`/manifest/gradle issues is common base :-/

Comment: I've posted a new issue in Xamarin Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51689

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Thanks for the bug link

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: @SushiHangover - Any chance you would be willing to share your build scripts (bash/.ps1) for the manifest fix-up?

Answer (score 0):

The main manifest file of your project is the higher priority manifest, so if you add the provider element to main manifest file and apply a merge rule marker for `android:authorities` attribute, the merger tools replaces the `android:authorities` value that you declare in the main manifest.

Declare `provider` element in main manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...
...

<application>

    <provider
        android:name="com.zendesk.belvedere.BelvedereFileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.belvedere.attachments"
        tools:replace=”android:authorities” >
    </provider>

</application>
```

Comment: It was the first thing I've tried. Unfortunately, it just adds [a new provider declaration](http://pastebin.com/T33CGbV0), but not replaces an existing one from aar.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Did you tried it with `tools:replace` attribute? merge match key is `android:name` and manifest merger must replaces the provider.

Comment: [Yes](https://gitlab.com/lassana/ZendeskXamarin/blob/3a30d78e4bd566b76995fcf08817a25045163a92/ZendeskSDK.Droid.Example2/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml), I did. There is [no much difference](http://pastebin.com/V1PwCZrV).

Comment: @Aryan This will not work as the `.aar`'s manifest file provider entry does not match the manually added in the app's manifest and thus another entry will be made. The only current way is to remove the the file provider entry from the `.aar` manifest....